# JavaScript table doesn't render in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have this JavaScript

```
function pickdet(Id) {
        //alert(Id);
        var dd = Id;

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: "/PVSigns1/GetDetails",
            data: { 'Id' : Id },
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                //alert('i dey here')
                var row = "";
                var baseurl = '@Url.Action("Edit","PVSigns1")' + '?Id=';
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    var clickUrl = baseurl + item.PVSignId;

                    //row += "<tr><td>" + item.VitalSigns.Sign + "</td><td>" + item.SignValue + "</td><td> <input type= 'button'  onclick= location.href = + '<Url.Action("Create", "PVSigns1", new { Id = item.PVSignId }) ' />" + "</td></tr>";
                    row += "<tr><td>" + item.VitalSigns.Sign + "</td><td>" + item.SignValue +
                        "</td><td> <button class='editbtn btn btn-xs btn-success' data-url = '" + clickUrl + "'> <i class='fa fa-edit fa-lg'></i> Edit</button></td></tr>";
                });
                $("#pvv").html(row);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                $("#pvv").html('Nothing to show <br /> <p />' + result);
            }
        });
    }

    $(function () {

        $("button.editbtn").click(function (e) {
            alert("url");
            e.preventDefault();
            //e.defaultPrevented();
            window.location.href = $(this).attr("url");
        });

    });
```

When I run it, it display perfectly on the browser, but the link created don't work, and when I view the page source, the tbody part which the code above is supposed to inject, doesn't get rendered.

This is what I get, Click on any of the green buttons 
in the top table, it loads the second table.  The issue is with the second table.

**Note: I am using JQuery Datatables.**

[image]

This the rendered output from page source

```
<div>
<h3> Details</h3>
<table id="Pv" class="table table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Sign</th>
            <th> Value </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="pvv">

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Notice `<tbody id="pvv">` is empty, not table elements there.  What is the issue?

Comment: add your code in jsfiddle for more information.

Comment: can you post the sample http response? Example json response.

Comment: place the click function inside the dom element

Comment: I have already tried that using the same given by @Haresh, When I did that, it frooze the buttons in the master table, clicking them doesn't load the second/details table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use delegation of dom element for click event. which element generated after binding event after existing dom

```
$("#Pv").on('click','button.editbtn', function (e) {
            alert("url");
            e.preventDefault();
            //e.defaultPrevented();
            window.location.href = $(this).attr("url");
});
```